# create two users for same sub category in a box in DJANGO

Tags: django

I have 4 Users(2 X CP_USER, 2 X CP_SCRNS) and two subgroups(Login stats and Application stats) but two of then belong to one group and another 2 belong to another group.

Here is the screenshot.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxlBu.png)

How to separate two group and display in the html page in the same box.Here is the reference[Here is the reference how the index page shouls look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpqba.png)
.

Here is my models page:
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

## Create your models here.

```
class Kpi_Data(models.Model):
kpi_key = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
kpi_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
kpi_value = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
kpi_Group = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
kpi_subgroup = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
kpi_delta_ind = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
```

Here is my views.py file

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Kpi_Data
from django.template import loader

## Create your views here.

```
def home(request):
return render(request,"myApp/index.html")


def info(request):
ac = Kpi_Data.objects.all()
template = loader.get_template('myApp/info.html')
Context = {
    'ac': ac,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(Context, request))
```

Here is my info.html page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       </style>
      </head>


     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 150%"></a>
    <div class = "logo"></div>
  <a href="#"><img src= "" width="190" height="70" alt=""></a>
        </div>
enter code here

    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="input-group search-box">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Search here...">
        </div>
    </form>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active"><i1 class="fa fa- 
     home"></i1></a>
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-item nav-link 
    dropdown-toggle user-action active">{{ request.headers.uid }}
    </br>{{ request.headers.role}}</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"> 
       </i> Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar- 
   o"></i> Calendar</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sliders"> 
   </i> Settings</a>
                <div class="divider dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="material- 
  icons">&#xE8AC;</i> Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   </nav>
     <body>

              <div class="sidebar">
                          <a class = "nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Reference Data</a>
     `enter code here`            <a  href="#">Report Registration</a>
                 <a href="#">Role Management</a>
                 <a  href="#">Role maintenence</a>
                 <a href="#">User Roles</a>
                 <a href="#">User Management</a>

            </br>
            </div>
    <h1>Login statistics</h1>
    <h2>Appication statictics</h2>

  <div class="footer fixed-bottom">
                <a href="#">@ Copyright Maryland.gov</a>
                <a href="#">All rights Reserved</a>
                 <a  href="#">Contatc us</a>
                 <a href="#">Privacy & Security</a>
                 <a  href="#">Accessbility</a>
            </div>

         </body>
            </html>

   Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code.

```
rows = Kpi_Data.objects.objects.values('kpi_group', 'kpi_subgroup', 
   'kpi_key').annotate(value=sum('kpi_value'))
L_C_U = L_C_S = A_C_U = A_C_S = 0`
for row in rows
  if (row[kpi_Group]=='LOGIN_STATIS' and row[kpi_subgroup]='CONSUMER_PORTAL' and row[kpi_key]='CP_USER'):
     L_C_U = row[value]
  elif (row[kpi_Group]=='LOGIN_STATIS' and row[kpi_subgroup]='CONSUMER_PORTAL' and row[kpi_key]='CP_SCRNS'):
     L_C_S = row[value]
  ....

Context = {
    'LCU': L_C_U,
    'LCS': L_C_S,
     ....
}
```

Then, in info.html, an template file, use LCU, LCS ... to display data.
I'm glad if above code would help you.

Comment: My Bad.It is Working.Thanks James

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works. Please give me feedback if you think it's ok.